# GDR citizens stood to be executed as they made their vain bids for western freedom

Tags: cold-war, german-unification

1. Does ***"western freedom"*** in the following context mean ***"to free up the western Germany"*** or ***"freedom in the style of western countries"***?
2. Which historical event is it referring to when it says ***"GDR citizens stood to be executed as they made their vain bids for western freedom"***?

Context:

Its other flanks situate it, of course, between the post-1989 Potsdamer Platz business and shopping hub, Brandenburg Gate and the Reichstag Parliament: iconic landmarks of Berlin history and the evolution of German nationhood as a whole. This is the exact terrain of Cold War separation and deadlock: the former death
strip (Todesstreifen), in fact, between eastern and western walls. This zone is the only possible place where the physical joins of a reunified cityscape can be located. But it is also the exact site of Germany’s one-time centre of governmental power and, therefore, inevitably ground tainted by national socialism. The memorial location itself was flanked by several ‘ministries of the Reich’, which as governmental buildings preceded the Nazis, of course, but nevertheless later came to epitomise Hitler’s rule, not least the Chancellory that was his formal headquarters. Embedding the memorial here amounts to
an extraordinarily powerful, palimpsest-like rewriting of this critical urban site. It not only proposes an engagement with both Nazi and Cold War pasts but also acknowledges the legacy of the Holocaust as a phenomenon that must be allocated central importance in Berlin’s emergence as Germany’s seat of government and capital city of choice after reunification. Here is where the orders of war and mass extermination emanated from. Here is also where disillusioned GDR citizens stood to be executed as ***they made their vain bids for
western freedom***. And here is where these histories now lie entombed in Eisenman’s stelae where they are subject, though, to myriad performances
of continuing human life as a multitude of bodies filter through the spaces between them.

Comment: Hello user19096, welcome to history.SE. I've edited your post to remove the WWII and Nazi tags and added the cold-war tag because you are asking about a post-war event.

Comment: Please source the quote.  Who said that, when and where?

Comment: Whoever wrote this text misunderstood the Holocaust Memorial, which does not entomb multiple histories and does not commemorate the dead of the GDR regime. Eisenman's stelae are quite specifically the "Memorial to the Murdered Jews of Europe".

Comment: As per Google books this seems to be taken from Nicholas Whybrow's "Art and the City" (https://books.google.de/books?id=36j3AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT159&lpg=PT159&dq=Here+is+also+where+disillusioned+GDR+citizens+stood+to+be+executed+as+they+made+their+vain+bids+for+western+freedom.&source=bl&ots=X2LOLiIuXZ&sig=A51PbKmT1Dam37bGIM9SfmoGYYI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqz9v_6rHNAhUGQpoKHUCFDGMQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=Here%20is%20also%20where%20disillusioned%20GDR%20citizens%20stood%20to%20be%20executed%20as%20they%20made%20their%20vain%20bids%20for%20western%20freedom.&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely "flowery" language. If it was translated from a German source, that didn't help, either.

- Germans in the GDR attempted to overthrow the Communist rule on [June 17th, 1953](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uprising_of_1953_in_East_Germany). GDR police and Soviet tanks suppressed this uprising. There were deaths and death sentences afterwards.
- Afterwards, the GDR government [prohibited emigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republikflucht) to the FRG. (While it is pretty common that countries limit who can *enter*, it is a fundamental human right to *leave* unless there are specific criminal charges pending.) The border was fortified first between the FRG and GDR and then between the GDR and [West Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin) (which had a special legal status under Allied law).

I suspect that the quote is a reference to deaths at the [Berlin Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deaths_at_the_Berlin_Wall). This makes the use of the word "executed" imprecise under most definitons. They were killed by the GDR government.

Comment: Does "for western freedom" in the highlighted sentence in the provided context mean  "to achieve freedom in the style of west countries" or "to free western Germany"?

Comment: @user127733, it is hard to guess what the author meant without having the book, but I *guess* he talked about fleeing to the FRG.